# I'm not able to select the dropdown option Baby under dropdown category on Amazon.in - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run below code to select Dropdown category baby
but failed open dropdown list on selenium

```
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
   Select dr2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));
   dr2.selectByValue("search-alias=baby");
    driver.close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiOsT.jpg)

Comment: What error message are you getting? Please describe how it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a delay, to wait for the elements visibility before accessing them.
The best way to do that is to use `WebDriverWait` `ExpectedConditions`.
This should work better:

```java
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(searchDropdownBox)));
Select dr2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));
dr2.selectByValue("search-alias=baby");
driver.close();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you It is working now perhaps i used wrong locator value - so i done some changes & code it working